# sudo applications not shows up

Tags: sudo, synaptic, thunar

if I try to launch an application from prompt with sudo, its window does not show up but I can see the icon on the status bar: if I launch thunar, it works, but if I launch sudo thunar, sudo GParted or sudo synaptic, I can see only the icon but the application it is stuck

Comment: Applications should not be launched with `sudo` from the command line.  If the application  needs elevated permissions it will ask you to enter your password like `gparted` will.  Make sure that your user account has sudo access.

Comment: Especially your file manager, never launch with `sudo`. This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What are the actual tasks you are trying to accomplish that have you believe you need to launch the application with `sudo`?  There is definitely a better path to achieve the same result.  Ask about that problem so that we can provide a more appropriate solution.  If you have multiple scenarios, you can ask multiple questions.

Comment: there a two way to start graphical programs `sudo -H whatever_you_want`  and pkexec..You can see wich actions are possible with `pkaction`  but normally you don't need to start gui program with granted rights.